# Nested object creation in cpp. What is the function call sequence in pseudo code below?

Tags: c++

Here is some code and I do not understand certain concepts. Please help!

Now in the below code, when I create some_obj1 and try to access the table in some_obj2 will I be able to access the internal_table? Is it created?

I feel that it will not, as I do nothing in the default constructor of some_obj1 and neither do I create it in the default constructor of some_obj2.

```
class some_obj1 {
 public: // Updated
    some_obj2 table; // table is a vector of int pointers.

    some_obj1() {
        //DO Nothing
    }
}

class some_obj2 {
 public: // Updated
    std::vector<int *> internal_table;

    some_obj2(){
        internal_table.push(new int[10]);
    }
}

main () {
    some_obj1 make_a_object;
    //Use the object created for some task.
    // Access the internal_table in some_obj2. Will I be able to access it? is it created?

}
```

Comment: Your sample code makes not much of sense for me, nor does it clarify, what you're actually asking about.

Comment: I want to understand if the internal_table in some_obj2 will be created. With the exact above setup of constructors and nesting

Comment: Asa a quick hint : If you have doubts regarding function / constructor calls, in the future use printf to debug their order. In the case above you will notice that some_obj2 constructor gets called.

Comment: Aside from the fact that all your constructors & members are private and `some_obj2` must be declared before `some_obj1`... your pseudo-code works. `make_a_object.table.internal_table[0]` *(which you can't construct or access because it's private)* will contain your pointers. But all this here is really bad pseudo-C++. You should not play with raw pointers... I can tell you'll leak them hard based on this question. So use a vector of vectors/arrays to store your ints.

Answer (score 0):

At the opening bracket of your constructor all members have been constructed - either default-constructed (if they have a default constructor) or uninitialized if they are of the Plain-Old-Data (POD) category such as ints or pointers.

Note that you will get a default constructor for classes and structs automatically if you do not declare one. This one will *also* construct your class-type members properly using their default constructor.

If you do not want to default construct something (or if you can't - because it might not have a default constructor) you should initialize it in your initializer list.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the "table" (of type some_obj1) is created even before the constructor some_ob1() is called? Is some_obj1() even called in this case?

Comment: The table is constructed before your constructor *body* runs. If you want it to have some sensible value, you either initialize it in the initializer list, or you assign some value in the constructor body.

Answer (score 0):

You have the simple rules of composition that are being used here.

The very first thing that is created when you do :

```
some_obj1 make_a_object;
```

the order in which things are created :

```
std::vector<int *> internal_table; //because some_obj2 will needs it
some_obj2 table; //because some_obj1 needs it
some_obj1 make_a_object; //is now finally ready
```

easy to detect if you use a debugger. 
the 3 lines just depict the order in which the objects are finished there creation it does not show he execution order because of course some_obj1 make_a_object is executed first. The point is that this code triggers first the creation of the other things, when that is complete, then the call to some_obj1 make_a_object will be complete.

also this code is doubtfull :

```
internal_table.push_back(new int[10]);
```

i think only one element, the first in the array will be pushed on the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do what you intend to do but you need to fix syntax and other issues like

1) Not declaring an access specifier for constructor will result in it being declared `private` which will not allow to create its object which is the basis for singleton design pattern.

2) There is no such method called `push` there is `push_back` provided in STL for vectors.

3) Class definition should end with a `;`

4) You will get an error that no type `some_obj2` to fix this you should do a forward declaration or follow a sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class some_obj2 {
   std::vector<int *> internal_table;

   public:
   some_obj2(){
      internal_table.push_back(new int[10]);
   }
};


class some_obj1 {
   some_obj2 table; // table is a vector of int pointers.

   public:
   some_obj1() {
      //DO Nothing
   }
};
int main () {
    some_obj1 make_a_object;
    //Use the object created for some task.
    // Access the internal_table in some_obj2. Will I be able to access it? is it created?
return 0;
}
```